# how can i write pyramid logic in php for given pattern?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

The pattern is given below And i need pyramid logic for given pattern.

[image: pyramid logic]

Comment: Looks like a homework.

Comment: Did you tried anything yet ?

Comment: @suhasini Please atleast give it try. search on google and still if you not find anything then asked with your some code samples ..

Comment: I tried a lot but i failed in that

Comment: @suhasini  Show us ur attempts

Comment: if you are not good in programming then doesn't matter in this case .. but show your algorithm for this question. Its a just logical based question. if you can write logic for this then anyone can write program for this. As @Daenarys mention looks like homework . So try to write Algorithm for it and then will write program to you. Start doing with `c programming` example you will find a lot pyramid pattern questions.

Comment: Read [this](http://cbasicprogram.blogspot.in/2012/04/number-patterns.html). Once you get the understanding of how these should be done, You will be able to do it.

Comment: Agree with Rahul Dambare. @suhasini just tried googling above question's subject. you will get lots of example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [`for`](http://php.net/for) loop with some basic logic should suffice.

```
<?php

$a = [6,8,6,7,3,5,5,4,1,1,9,5,1,5,6];

$x = 0;
for($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++) {
   if(in_array($i, [5,9,12,14])) { //if we need a break point
      $x++; //increment the break counter
      echo PHP_EOL . str_repeat(' ', $x); //new line plus indentation
   }
   echo $a[$i] .' '; //echo the number and spacing
}
```

https://eval.in/538507

Comment: You're welcome. Since it's solved your problem and is the only solution, please read: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246338)

Comment: Those are the iterator break points. 5 iterations, we need to break (ie: go to the next line)